# .htaccess not working even with AllowOverride set to All

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-ec2

I have a project with codeigniter that works completely fine on the localhost, no errors at all. But after hosting it with Amazon EC2, i keep getting the "404 page not found" error. I have changed AllowOverride to All and I almost sure that my htaccess file is being used because I put jibberish in it and it resulted in an "Internal server error". I would appreciate any help i can get.

Comment: `mod_rewrite` is enable on server?

Comment: @urfusion yes it is

Comment: do some random change in your htaccess, if it gives you 500 internal server error then it is working, if not check host file again

Comment: @urfusion i did that already as stated in my description. It gave the error so i think it does work. What else do yo think could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I had a very similar problem with Ubuntu Server 11.10 and LAMP. I had to run the command

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

which did the trick for me. Maybe it's the solution for you or some other people coming in here.

And restart the apache after running this command.

Comment: Not only this command. After running this command you have to reload/restart apache

Comment: @Siddhesh I already have Module rewrite enabled. I dont know what else could be the problem

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my issue but i am not really sure what the problem might have been. All I did was re-download a new Codeigniter folder on my localhost and replace most of the folders in my project with the one i downloaded (apart from Application and vendor). I also changed the name of my controller from 'main.php' to 'Main.php'. Thats all i did and now it works. Thank you to those who tried to help.